# How to implement the "System.out.println(ClassName::MethodName <then my message>)" of Eclipse in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to know if there is the same feature as in **eclipse** to automatically generate and print the `System.out.println(ClassName::MethodName <then my message>)` functionality (which will print the *class* name and *method* name for debugging in the *console*) in *Netbeans* also.

For example, in Eclipse Editor, Typing

> **syst + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd>**

will auto generate a System.out.println(ClassName::MethodName ) type output in the console.

Is such a method available in Netbeans?

As of now, I have only two methods here in Netbeans:

> **sout + <kbd>Tab</kbd>**

(System.out.println()) and

> **soutv + <kbd>Tab</kbd>**

(System.out.println(prints the variable used just above the line)) automatically.

Let me rephrase, instead of myMethod1, I want to get the enclosing method name.

Eg. :

```
public class X {

  public void myMethod1(int a) {
    System.out.println(X::myMethod1()); // This should be produced when I type the Code-Template abbreviation (example: syst) and press tab (or corresponding key).
  }
}

public class Y {

  public void myMethod2(int b) {
    System.out.println(Y::myMethod2()); // This should be produced when I type the Code-Template abbreviation (example: syst) and press tab (or corresponding key).
  } 
}
```

---

**Update:**

With the following code template:

> syst = System.out.println("${classVar editable="false" currClassName
>   default="getClass()"}");

I am able to print the classname, but still no clue for the Method name.

Comment: Never heard of `System.out.traceln`

Comment: Do you mean `println` instead of `traceln`?

Comment: Yes, You were right.. There is no System.out.traceln.. Actually what I meant was SystemTrace feature which is actually System.out.println(ClassName::MethodName <then my message>), where ClassName and MethodName is generated automatically by the editor.

Comment: Just look at http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/macro-keywords.html. You can record a macro and assign it to a key.

Comment: Take a look at Bug 160042: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=160042

Comment: I second @vikiiii recomendation. Using log4j or other logger implementation would give you class and method information and is a better tool than using `System.out` in the long run.

Comment: is it what you are looking for? System.out.println("${enclosing_type}.${enclosing_method}()");

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Logger` to implement this.

[Apache log4j](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/&ei=08-MUKjAKsLIrQfPpIGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHa3hT5r4h5P2115jiUMpTxZpwYHQ&sig2=9GFiXPUpK7-mNeMB1zw66g) is a Java-based logging utility.

Using `log4j` or other logger implementation would give you `class` and `method` information and every commercial application use `logger` than using `System.out.`

The logger also gives the ability to define different levels of importance of the logged messages and the ability to use different sink for the output - the console, a file, etc.

Also it's easy to enable or disable only some type of message when using a logger - for example you don't want to see every debug message in production.

If your application is using `spring framework`, then you can use use [Log4j and AOP](http://www.jtmelton.com/2008/01/24/a-simple-spring-aop-tutorial/) to implement this.

```
Setting the log level
```

There are 5 log levels that you can set:

```
`FATAL` — logs only fatal errors

`ERROR` — logs all errors

`WARN` — logs warnings, and all errors

`INFO` — logs information, warnings, and all errors

`DEBUG` — logs debug information, and all other levels
```

Sample `log4j.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
 <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} 
      %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/> 
    </layout>
     </appender>
       <root>
      <priority value="debug"></priority>
      <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

In this configuration file , you can choose what you want to store .

Like `%m` means it will store `method name` .
Similarly others, you have to read it for different usage .
Good part is you can customized it according to your needs.

Comment: Actually I have log4j in my framework and I am using that.. But i was thinking if it is possible for the same feature we have in eclipse to be implemented here also..

Comment: No currently there is no feature in eclipse that can enable you to do that. But you can place a feature request to the open source community  providing a proper description to them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, after some testing, I see no way to achieve the same functionality in netbeans. Perhaps you could just stick with eclipse, as it seems to have worked well in the past for you.

If you really wanted to get this done in NetBeans (I still prefer (and recommend) eclipse), I would recommend taking a look at [this plugin](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/NetBeans_DTrace_GUI_Plugin_0_4.html), and possibly editing it to add the SystemTrace functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a logging framework as suggested by @vikiiii. I would go further and suggest you look at [sl4fj](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.slf4j.org/&ei=NOyNUN3mAsaUiQfjvoHICw&usg=AFQjCNEcMpiXAjIDjIVe-yjiBy8oQ_QJGA) which provides a seamless way of incorporating logging frameworks, including log4j. Whilst this may seem like more work (and more to learn), there are very good performance reasons for not using `System.out.println()`.

Specifically, `System.out.println()` blocks all threads whilst it writes, impacting the performance of any significant application as described [here](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2010/11/system-out-println-performance/)